# MySQL Roles.RemoveUserFromRole not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, roles

There seems to be a bug in MySQL where  Roles.RemoveUserFromRole does not work if the user name contains a slash.  The problem is described in detail here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77264 but I can't seem to locate any work-around.  I've tried to escape the "\" using userName.Replace(@"\", @"\") but that doesn't make a difference.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just rolling my own until this is fixed in the MySQL role provider.  Here's the code (nHibernate flavored) if anyone needs it.

```
    private static bool RemoveUserFromRole(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var sess = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().OpenSession();

        const string query = @"
                                delete 
                                from my_aspnet_usersinroles 
                                where 
                                    roleId in (select id from my_aspnet_roles where name = :roleName)
                                    and userId = :userId;
                                ";
        var result = sess.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                .SetParameter("userId", userId)
                .SetParameter("roleName", roleName)
                .ExecuteUpdate();

        return result >= 0;

    }
```